# Get text between markers that span over multiple lines

Tags: sed

Say I've got input that looks like this:

```
something

START MARKER
foo
I
just
want
this
foo
END MARKER

something else

foo
I don't want this
foo
```

Can I use `sed` to get the text that is between both `START MARKER` and `END MARKER` *and* between the `foo`s, which appear as nested markers?

Currently I'm able to do this with two passes:

```
sed -n '/START MARKER/,/END MARKER/ { // !p; }' < input \
| sed -n '/foo/ !p;'
```

However, I feel like this isn't as optimal as it could be...

Comment: Possibly, but not easily. Why sed? Why not GNU awk,  pcregrep, Perl, Ruby, or something capable of parsing more complex expressions?

Comment: Only because I assumed it would be easy in sed :) If not, then I'll stick with Awk

Comment: For your given sample, `sed -n '/START MARKER/,/END MARKER/ { //d; /foo/d; p}'` will also work

Comment: @sundeep This assumes balanced `foo` lines and start/end markers. While true in the example provided, if you aren't looking at a multi-line pattern space you can't really test the validity of nested markers, and some versions of sed may not handle first or last lines properly this way. A more robust solution would require appending to the pattern or hold space and conditional branching IMHO.

Comment: What behavior do you expect if there are more than two `foo` lines between your outer markers? And if you have nested outer markers?

Comment: I control the input, so that would never happen.

Comment: @sundeep's comment is "good enough" for my purposes; if it's made into an answer, I'll accept it. The others are certainly helpful, so I've upvoted them, but are a bit too cryptic/overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's attempt can be simplified to delete the lines containing `foo` along with the start and end markers:

```bash
sed -n '/START MARKER/,/END MARKER/ {//d; /foo/d; p}'
```

This works with `GNU sed`, but other implementations might differ w.r.t. the behavior of the empty pattern `//`.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood, but I thought the OP wanted to restrict the filter to a range within a range. Unless `foo` is the line following the first range and also the line just before the closing first range, this solution will print not print `foo` lines but may print too many lines.

Comment: @potong OP commented under the question to post this as a solution, so I guess it works for their use case...

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En '/^START MARKER/{:a;n;/foo/,/foo/ {//!p}; /^END MARKER/d; ba}' input_file
I
just
want
this
```

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

While you asked for a sed solution, a more extensible and *testable* solution is available to you in Ruby (and to a lesser extent in Perl, which also supports a flip-flop operator). I present it here in various forms to show why it may be a better choice for something that you plan to re-use or adapt, rather than as a one-off solution.

### A Ruby Solution with More Firepower

Doing this in Ruby provides more power and flexibility. You can do it as a Ruby one-liner, as follows:

```bash
# Assumes the data is in a file named "text".
ruby -ane '
  if ($_ =~ /^START MARKER/ ... $_ =~ /^END MARKER/) &&
     ($_ =~ /^foo/ ... $_ =~ /^foo/)
    puts $_ unless $_ =~ /^(?:START|END) MARKER$/ || /^foo$/
  end' text
```

This prints:

> ```
> I
> just
> want
> this
> ```

Note that by using the Ruby flip-flop range operaor with `...` instead of `..` your second-level markers can use the same demarcation (e.g. `foo`) for both starting and stopping a selection. You could do the same with first-level markers (e.g. just `MARKER` instead of `START MARKER` and `END MARKER`), but *don't* use the same markers for both the first and second levels unless you are prepared to build a more complex parser that can handle true nesting rather than just start and end pairs.

#### A More Detailed, Step-by-Step Example

The following does the same thing as above, but rather than using AWK-like auto-splitting of lines for processing we read the whole file into an Array object from *within* the script before selecting and rejecting specific lines.

```rb
ruby -e '
  @lines = File.readlines "text"                                                  
  @lines.select! { _1 if _1 =~ /^START MARKER/ ... _1 =~ /^END MARKER/ }
  @lines.reject! { _1.match? /^(?:START|END) MARKER/ }
  @lines.select! { _1 if _1 =~ /^foo/ ... _1 =~ /^foo/ }
  @lines.reject! { _1.start_with? "foo" }
  puts @lines
'
```

This will correctly print out:

> ```
> I
> just
> want
> this
> ```

While the results are the same, this may be more readable and more extensible if you want to make complex changes or add additional rules.

### Edge Cases Handled by Examples Above

#### Multiple Second-Level Markers

Either of the solutions above will correctly handle cases where you have multiple 2nd level markers in your text like:

```
no line
START MARKER
foo
bar
baz
foo
quux
foo
wubble
foo
END MARKER
no line
```

> ```
> bar
> baz
> wubble
> ```

#### Missing Terminal Markers

The following inputs will also result in expected output using the examples above:

```
no line
START MARKER
foo
bar
baz
foo
quux
foo
wubble
foo
no line
```

```
no line
START MARKER
foo
bar
baz
foo
quux
foo
wubble
END MARKER
no line
```

```
no line
START MARKER
foo
bar
baz
foo
quux
foo
wubble
END MARKER
foo
no line
```

### Caveats

Your format is somewhat brittle. While you can do a lot with Ruby to handle various edge cases, pathological cases like:

1. missing both first- and second-level starting markers
2. missing a terminal first-level marker *and* having second-level markers outside the intended range
3. missing terminal second-level markers when other second-level starting markers are present inside the first-level markers

are just some examples of where this code could still fail. You can easily check that your markers are balanced with code like:

```rb
@lines = File.readlines "text"                                                  
@lines.select! { _1 if _1 =~ /^START MARKER/ ... _1 =~ /^END MARKER/ }
raise "unbalanced first-level markers" unless
    @lines.grep(/^(?:START|END) MARKER$/).count.modulo(2).zero?

@lines.reject! { _1.match? /^(?:START|END) MARKER/ }
@lines.select! { _1 if _1 =~ /^foo/ ... _1 =~ /^foo/ }
raise "unbalanced second-level markers" unless
  @lines.grep(/^foo$/).count.modulo(2).zero?

@lines.reject! { _1.start_with? "foo" }
puts @lines
```

However, if you do this then you lose the ability to handle missing first- or second-level end markers, but you gain the ability to stop processing if you have missing markers or unbalanced markers that could result in incorrect output. It just depends on how well-structured your markup really is.

### Extendability

The Ruby solution is pretty extensible. Because each line is stored as a String object in an Array, you can slice, dice, and transform the output in various ways to handle additional edge cases. You can also add additional logic for handling other edge cases, or create a real parser that can treat sections of your text as sub-arrays or other data structures rather than just doing line-by-line processor or relying on the flip-flop operator to select the lines you want to display.

Even better, you have the ability to store and debug intermediate values in a REPL such as irb for testing. The ability to raise exceptions when your data is not conformant to your needs is also something that can save you time and trouble in the future.

Comment: Thanks for going to so much trouble with your answer. I'm running in a restricted environment, so installing Ruby is a bit overkill for my need. Still, it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/START MARKER/,/END MARKER/!d;/foo/,/foo/!d;//d' file
```

Delete everything not in the range between `START MARKER` and `END MARKER`.

Delete everything not in the range between `foo` and `foo`.

Delete everything `foo`.

Print the rest.

or:

```
sed -n '/START MARKER/{:a;n;/foo/!ba;:b;n;//!{p;bb}};d' file
```